# How do I set up local files and production files in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a simple web app that is now being hosted on Heroku.

My secret key is set up as an environment variable so that it is not being pushed to a remote repository but when I try to push these changes to Heroku I get this error:

```
raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

I guess this is because it doesn't have access to my environment variable, so how do I set up a separate settings file for production that will hold this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was wrong here.

Basically Heroku needs to also have an environment variable that needs to be set up. This can be done by using this command:

heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='keyhere'

More detail can be found on [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars)

This is a better way of storing the key as it is not saved within a file.